# CSS how do I let max width override min width?

Tags: css, width

I want to make a div that is

80vw if 80vw > 1000px

1000px if 80vw <= 1000px and if 1000px <= 100vw

100vw if 1000px > 100vw

I tried the following:

```
div {
    width: 80vw;
    min-width: 1000px;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

This would work if max-width overrides min-width, but it does not: [Why doesn't max-width override min-width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063771/why-doesnt-max-width-override-min-width)

I know there is a simple solution using @media, but I want to know if this is possible with just width, min-width, and max-width.

Comment: Use media queries instead

Comment: I know there is a simple solution using @media, but I want to know if this is possible with just width, min-width, and max-width.

Comment: is not `    width: 1000px;
    min-width: 80vw;
    max-width: 100vw;`fitting your needs ?

Comment: get ride of width. Use min-width as your smallest setting and then max-width as your largest, Such as min-width: 80vw; max-width: 100vw;

Comment: No, `max-width` won't override `min-width`, as that is how it works. In your case though, there's a workaround, besides `@media` query's, where one swap the value's between `width` and `min-width`, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/cpje297g/